# Google fonts not working when I select all h1, h2, h3

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

I am trying to import a couple of Google fonts into my HTML/CSS by selecting all header tags and p tags and such at the top of my css. For example:

```
h1 h2 h3 {
  font-family: 'Trade Winds', cursive;
}
```

But this isn't working. I triple-checked, I have no other font-family rules anywhere in the file so it's not being overwritten, by me or any other linked file. It *does* work when I apply it directly into some other set of rules like this:

```
section {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.78);
        grid-column: 2/3;
        display: grid;
        font-family: 'Trade Winds', cursive;
}
```

but I obviously am not inclined to hard-code every relevant rule set as that's just redundant. Am I missing something about the way CSS tag selectors work?

Comment: h1, h2, h3 {...} ?

Comment: Jupp. You need a comma. `h1, h2, h3`.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to comma seperate your h tags so

```
h1 h2 h3 {
  font-family: 'Trade Winds', cursive;
}
```

Should be

```
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Trade Winds', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I tried that.... well that was silly. Thank you!

Comment: @panrosmithe Your welcome! Accept the answer if it helped you